# Flask run error python, No module named flask in virtual environment

Tags: python, flask

Apologies, have hunted around to an answer to this problem, and seen people with similar issues, but with no luck resolving this so far.

I'm trying to set up a simple Flask app, under a virtual enivoronment (`venv`), which has flask installed. I have a folder under my main directory, `simple_app/`, which has a single file, `__init__.py`, the contents of which are:

```py
    from flask import Flask

    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)

        @app.route('/')
        def mainPage():
            return 'Hi!'

        return app

    # to try and run app from script
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = create_app()
        app.run()
```

I have FLASK_APP and FLASK_ENV specified via `.env`. If I try to `flask run` I get the following output:

```
 $ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "simple_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 ...\venv\scripts\python.exe No module named ...venv\Scripts\flask
```

I can insert `print()` statements, and the output of these will show up, along with this error.

However if I run `python simple_app/__init__.py` my app launches perfectly fine (as `"__init__"`).

Additionally, if I run `flask routes` I see

```
$ flask routes
Endpoint  Methods  Rule
--------  -------  -----------------------
mainPage  GET      /
static    GET      /static/<path:filename>
```

so that Flask does seem to know about my app.

I've used this type of structure before without problems, so not quite sure what is going wrong here, although I am fairly new to Flask.

Thanks very much for any help anyone might be able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your setup. I've just created exactly the same app, with (from what I can tell) the same environment, and things work fine. You've not specified which version of Python you're using, so here are the full set of steps that I took (perhaps you can spot something you've missed):

- used Python 3.7.4
- created virtual environment using `python -m venv venv`
- activated virtual environment using `source venv/bin/activate`
- installed flask with `pip install Flask`
- created the folder structure below, and copied your code into a single file
- ran the following commands:

```sh
export FLASK_APP=simple_app`
export FLASK_ENV=development`
flask run
```

This resulted in the app working as expected.

The folder structure, with just one .py file, is as follows:

```
.
└── simple_app
    └── __init__.py
```

The contents of that .py file are exactly the same as you've stated:

`__init__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def mainPage():
        return 'Hi!'

    return app

# to try and run app from script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

```sh
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "simple_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: [snip]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There isn't anything that leaps out there as being different from how I have things set up, but I'll check once I'm back at my computer whether I've got anything mismatched to how you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked my set-up and it is in principle all the same. Issue seems to be a bug with this version of Werkzeug

Comment: Aha - are you Windows then? My setup is MacOS. Feel free to upvote my answer it it was useful to you.